# How would a malicious group of co-signers use a hash collision to sign an unintended message?

Tags: hash, cryptocurrency, schnorr-signature, collision-attack

According to [BIP340](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki):

> However, a major drawback of this optimization is that finding collisions in a short hash function is easy. This complicates the implementation of secure signing protocols in scenarios in which a group of mutually distrusting signers work together to produce a single joint signature (see Applications below). In these scenarios, which are not captured by the SUF-CMA model due its assumption of a single honest signer, a promising attack strategy for malicious co-signers is to find a collision in the hash function in order to obtain a valid signature on a message that an honest co-signer did not intend to sign.

In the version of Schnorr used by BIP340, the arguments to the hash function are given by the following:

$e=\text{hash}(R || P || m)$

In order to sign an unintended message, a malicious signer would need to find a collision between two different messages:

$e=\text{hash}(R||P||m_0)=\text{hash}(R||P||m_1)$

But this implies $m_0$ is not committed to before calculating $R$. It seems strange that this "attack" requires convincing the honest signer to sign a particular message $m_0$ *after* they already calculated their particular $R_H$ value. If $m$ were committed before generating $R$ is this type of attack still possible?

Answer (score 1):

The point is you (and me) did not read the document properly;

In your quoted part they consider attacking Schnorr signature variant, To simplify I will use a shorter notation as $H(m)$

Yes, they consider the collision for the attack. If there is a signature $sign(prv,H(m))$ and you want to forge you need the pre-image attacks on the hash function $H$ so that you can claim that $m'$ is was the intended message.

In the quoted part of the Bip340 document, this is the case. You want your co-signer to sign a message that they normally don't want to sign. So you find some collision pairs $m_i \neq m'_i$ such that $H(m_i) = H(m'_i)$ with additional property; your cosigner will sign for $m_i$ but not for $m'_i$ for which the second one is on your benefit but not their. They will not be suspicious of $m_i$ to sign and they will sign and you will use the $m'_i$ as the signed message to gain an advantage against your co-signer.

later they wrote as;

> Since we would like to avoid the fragility that comes with short hashes, the $e$ variant does not provide significant advantages. We choose the $R$-option, which supports batch verification.

If you commit $m$ before signature, then neither collision nor pre-images will work. Let see;

- $commit = H(m)$
- calculate $R$
- prepare the hash for signature

  $\text{hash}(R || P || m)$

In this case, the malicious co-signer need to attack the $commit$ to find another second message $m'$ such $H(m) = H(m')$, i.e. execute a second pre-image attack and this will hold for $\text{hash}(R || P || m) = \text{hash}(R || P || m')$, too. Quite not possible.

Comment: @knaccc It is too hard to find that work both. I've no information about multi-preimage attacks probability for such cases. At least it should be harder than 128-bit search.

Comment: I think the reason this question has caused so much confusion is that they are indicating that the problem is that an $(e, s)$ signature pair with short hashes would "complicate the implementation of secure signing protocols in scenarios in which a group of mutually distrusting signers work together to produce a single joint signature". However, since they never explained what the signing protocol would be for the $(e, s)$ variant that they rejected, we need to figure out ourselves what that protocol would have been, in order to see how it would be vulnerable to birthday collisions.

Comment: @knaccc I found some of the BIP very badly written not close to rfcs.

Comment: I found this [blog post](https://medium.com/blockstream/insecure-shortcuts-in-musig-2ad0d38a97da) from a researcher at Blockstream to be quite helpful. It seems like there might be situations in which $m$ is shared *after* the exchange of nonces. For example, nonces may be pre-shared in lightning as an optimization to reduce the number of communication rounds.

Note, however, the blog post said this optimization was insecure and only nonce-commitments should be pre-shared, so I'm not sure if sending messages after the nonce would ever happen in practice.